# Зачем нужна эта запятая и почему без нее не работает скрипт?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зачем нужна эта запятая и почему без нее не работает скрипт?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: Очевидно, эта запятая является разделителем аргументов функции

Answer (score 3):

> Зачем нужна эта запятая

Таков синтасис `console.log` (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Он может принимать не одну строку или переменную, а много переменных, перечисленных через запятую. В итоге значение каждой из них будет выведено в консоль.

> почему без нее не работает скрипт?

Потому что между данными (строкой и переменной) отсутствует оператор конкатенации (плюсик). И будет в итоге ошибка синтаксиса:

`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`